# Is $(x^{2} + 2x)W(x)$, where $W(x)$ is the Weierstrass function, non-monotonic for every subinterval in its domain $x \in [-1, 1]$ that contains 0?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So far, I have shown that $f(x)=(x^{2} + 2x)W(x)$ is differentiable at 0, where the parameters of the Weierstrass function are $a = \frac{1}{2}$ and $b = 3$, and $f'(0)$ = 4. I am fairly certain that $f(x)$ is non-differentiable everywhere else on the domain $[-1, 1]$ because $x^{2} + 2x$ has no other roots in that interval, and when I calculated the derivative of $f$ at $0$, I noticed that the fact that $x = 0$ is a root of $x^{2} + 2x$ led to the simplification that allowed me to calculate the derivative, although I have not proven this statement yet. My question is, given the above information, can I say that $f(x)$ is non-monotonic for every subinterval in its domain that contains 0? If so, I would like to prove it, but I am not aware of how to approach the proof. This question is inspired by the following [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719995/does-there-exist-a-nowhere-differentiable-everywhere-continous-monotone-somewh#).

Comment: $(x^{2} + 2x)W(x)$ is almost certainly non-monotonic in every interval (and $x^2 + 2x$ can almost certainly be replaced by any polynomial, probably by any locally Lipschitz function), and I suspect this can be deduced easily from known non-Hölder continuity properties of the Weierstrass function obtained by G. H. Hardy in 1916. See "but neither of them satisfies ..." at the end of 1.33 on p. 303 of [*Weierstrass’s non-differentiable function*](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1916-017-03/S0002-9947-1916-1501044-1/). **(continued)**

Comment: I'll be too busy the next few days to look at this sufficiently to write an appropriate answer, so if anyone else wishes to write an answer based on what I said about Hardy's result, that's fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ were differentiable at some $x$ different from $0$,then $W$ would be differentiable at $x$ since it would be the quotient of two differentiable functions. Hence $f$ is only differentiable at the origin. Now if $f$ were monotone in some interval, then by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, $f$ would be differentiable at a.e. Point in that interval, which is a contradiction. There is probably a more direct way to do this…